# Unable to run mongod server on CentOS

Tags: mongodb, centos

When i try to run my mongod server on CentOS the result of `npm start` is this error:

```
root@server[Taxi]# npm start
> vframework@0.0.1 start /home/user/public_html/Taxi
> node server
/home/user/public_html/Taxi/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/error.js:72
const MongoParseError = function(message) {
^^^^^
```

the version of mongod is 2.4.14 and when i run the `#mongod -v` command i got this error

```
root@server [Taxi]# mongod -v
Fri Mar 30 19:07:42.038 BackgroundJob starting: DataFileSync
Fri Mar 30 19:07:42.038 versionArrayTest passed
Fri Mar 30 19:07:42.069 shardKeyTest passed
Fri Mar 30 19:07:42.069 isInRangeTest passed
Fri Mar 30 19:07:42.069 shardObjTest passed
Fri Mar 30 19:07:42.096 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=24586 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db/ 64-bit host=server
Fri Mar 30 19:07:42.096 [initandlisten] db version v2.4.14
Fri Mar 30 19:07:42.096 [initandlisten] git version: nogitversion
Fri Mar 30 19:07:42.096 [initandlisten] build info: Linux buildvm-11.phx2.fedoraproject.org 4.7.2-201.fc24.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Aug 26 15:58:40 UTC 2016 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_41
Fri Mar 30 19:07:42.096 [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
Fri Mar 30 19:07:42.096 [initandlisten] options: { verbose: true }
Fri Mar 30 19:07:42.138 [initandlisten] User Assertion: 10310:Unable to lock file: /data/db/mongod.lock. Is a mongod instance already running?
Fri Mar 30 19:07:42.176 [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 10310 Unable to lock file: /data/db/mongod.lock. Is a mongod instance already running?, terminating
Fri Mar 30 19:07:42.177 dbexit: 
Fri Mar 30 19:07:42.177 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
Fri Mar 30 19:07:42.177 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
Fri Mar 30 19:07:42.177 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close sockets...
Fri Mar 30 19:07:42.177 [initandlisten] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
Fri Mar 30 19:07:42.177 [initandlisten] shutdown: lock for final commit...
Fri Mar 30 19:07:42.177 [initandlisten] shutdown: final commit...
Fri Mar 30 19:07:42.177 [initandlisten] shutdown: closing all files...
Fri Mar 30 19:07:42.179 [initandlisten] closeAllFiles() finished
Fri Mar 30 19:07:42.179 dbexit: really exiting now
```

i added a mongod.config file to path /etc/ fo specify the server adress and this is it's content

```
root@server [etc]# cat mongod.conf 
logpath=/var/log/mongo/mongod.log
port=27027
bind_ip=0.0.0.0
dbpath=/var/lib/mongo
replSetName: rs0
```

Comment: Per the error message "Unable to lock file: /data/db/mongod.lock. Is a mongod instance already running?" .. is there a `mongod` already running? While not specific to your startup error, I would also recommend upgrading to a supported version of MongoDB (currently 3.2 or newer). MongoDB 2.4 was originally released in March 2013 and reached end of life in March 2016. There have been significant changes and improvements since 2.4 so you are likely to run into issues resolved in later releases. Since 2.4 is no longer tested or supported by official drivers, you may also run into novel challenges.

Comment: i'm just working in a my client server, he is using monbod in other apps and he limits me to that, when i check the status od mongod service i find it 'stoped' but when i start it it fail without any error message

Comment: How are you starting & stopping MongoDB? You should ideally be [managing as a service](https://docs.mongodb.com/v2.4/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-red-hat-centos-or-fedora-linux/#run-mongodb) which should use your config file and ensure consistent invocation (user permissions, data & log paths, config options). With MongoDB 2.4 the invocation should be `sudo service mongod start`. If you want to start manually using the given config file, you could run with `mongod -f /etc/mongod.conf --fork`, but this is generally the wrong thing to do for a production environment.

Comment: i think the poroblem is with the server's system, i have a root access when i try to uninstall mongod tells me that there is no one on thhe sys, also if i want to upgrade, if i try to install it tell me that there is already a version using sudo service mongod start get me to error with no error messege or log file or anything